# Is it possible to remove the gutenberg duotone effect on hover?

Tags: block-editor

I'm trying to find a way to have the duotone effect removed when the mouse hovers over the image. I had done this on an old theme with CSS – before the gutenberg duotone feature was added.

I can find a lot of information online about removing the feature entirely. That is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```css
[class*="wp-block"][class]:hover > img {
  filter: none;
}
```

That ruleset works for hover on either Image or Cover blocks but you may want to write less generic selector for it depending on your intent.